# How to launch a C# windows form application from Outlook?

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

I have a Windows form application that, among other things, sends an email to users when they are assigned to an "action." In the email I want to put a link that will open the exe and pass in parameters of which action.

The exe will be in a shared network drive something like H:\Software\Builds\program.exe

I've found how to launch it, but not how to pass in parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing the parameters like so:  `C:\whatever.exe -<your parameter>` . Then read the parameter as an argument

For example:  if you have the exe as `C:\whatever.exe -<your parameter>`  in the `void Main(string[] args)`  you would do the following:

```
 void Main (string[] args)
 {
    foreach (var item in args)
    {
        var parameter=item;  

        // do whatever you wish with parameter  
    }
 }
```

Comment: the parameters are passed to the `string[] args` of the `void Main`

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? This is the most OBVIOUS part of the whole problem! @DJBurb pray tell how you actually launch the file with its parameters from outlook (!?) I'm certainly hitting a brick wall everywhere I search...